# Support on C# (displaying report on Crystal Report)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing a desktop application with C#. However, when I run the application to see the report, only report viewer form (blank form) is displayed and unable to see a crystal report data (which is CPSummary.rpt in this case ). The data table (**dtgetbydate**) works fine and fetches data from the database. Here's the piece of code that runs the report.

```
    CashPosition.Report.CPSummary sumrep = new CashPosition.Report.CPSummary();

     void getReportbyDate()
      {
        DataTable dtgetbydate = dac.getrepbydate((DateTime)dtpFrm.Value, (DateTime)dtpTo.Value);
        sumrep.SetDataSource(dtgetbydate);
        reportviewer.ReportSource = sumrep;
        reportviewer.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Appreciate your support in advance.

Comment: yes Henk, the data table has all the data from SQL db

Comment: I was thinking of sending you the screen shot of the data table with its data. However, here I can not insert picture, right?